# Serenity MVC Framework use Web Service

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I love the Serenity MVC framework and would like to use it as much as possible. I am returning data from a web service and would like to implement the framework using the return `List<>`. I know it is built on the Entity Frame work, but is it possible to have an override where we can get the data from a web service rather than a database?

Comment: What exactly is the *Serenity MVC framework*? I can't find a tag that matches what your after.

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/559ec6fc-feef-4077-b6d5-5a99408a6681

Comment: About Serenity MVC: http://serenity.is/

Answer (score 2):

You should derive your request and response classes from ServiceRequest and ServiceResponse then you can accept any parameter type inside it, e.g:

`MyResponse : ServiceResponse
   {
       Result: List< Something >
   }`